# Error while trying to stream TIDAL from Android to NVIDIA Shield

Tags: chromecast

I just downloaded the [TIDAL app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aspiro.tidal&hl=en) on my android phone and tried casting it to my NVIDIA Shield. The TIDAL app has a build in functionality to do exactly that. So I open the app, start playing a song and select the cast to shield action. After that I can see the TIDAL logo on my TV screen, but the song stops playing and the app becomes inresponsive.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see the app grays out everything on the screen.

I have absolutely no idea what is happening here, but maybe someone has experienced a similar issue?

Casting the screen works through other apps, so I'm pretty sure it's related to TIDAL.

I've reset my SHIELD and reinstalled the TIDAL app without any success.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the Tidal App on my Samsung S6 and my Ipad. The track shows up momentarily on the Shield then it cuts to a Tidal splash screen, with no sound. As you say, everything else casts OK so it's probably a Tidal bug! PS Have just found that the problem only exists if 'Hi Fi' is selected, lowering the quality to 'High' cures the problem but that's not the quality that I'm paying £20 a month for! This bug exists when casting to other hardware too !

Comment: Has this gotten any better? I was hoping to get a Chromecast audio for Tidal and saw there were many initial issues, but wasn't sure if things have improved recently.

Comment: @jon_wu Haven't tried it recently. I instead installed the tidal.apk directly on the shield, which works besides the Hifi streaming feature.